# 18.04 boots to black screen

Tags: gnome

I have a little problem. I recently bought an Asus X541UVK, with an Intel core I3-7100U, and a GeForce 920MX, with 4GB RAM. I tried to install ubuntu 18.04 on this machine, but after the installing finished succesfully, at first boot, after splash screen, the screen turns off. Ctrl+alt+f1 doesn't work. I also tried fedora, which has gnome too, but after login, even a simple action like opening the activities or turning WiFi on, completely frozens the desktop. I also tried other distros, like kde neon or deepin which works fine. What's happening? Sorry for my English, this is not my native language.

Comment: After installing Ubuntu 18.04 have to tried ctrl alt f2 f3 f4 etc?? You will access tty. From there you can turnoff nomodeset. https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu

Comment: I tried also nomodeset, it freezes after grub

Comment: The screen is not black, is turned off. No image, no light, nothing.

Comment: Your problem description points to a graphics driver issue of some sort. The linked question deals with those regardless of the specific symptoms.

Answer (score -1):

buddy, you must do one thing:
Try to clean up all disk before installing **Ubuntu 18.04**. I also have faced  that issue like that but ultimately it worked. Try to make a bootable pendrive by **RUFUS latest version**, if it is helpful to you.

Comment: I used Rufus, etcher, unetbootin,etc. I tried to install ubuntu clean, dual boot, uefi mode, legacy mode, i disabled secure boot. I installed updates during installation. Nothing, absolutely nothing!

Comment: Hi chandra, welcome to askubuntu! Post your answer according to https://askubuntu.com/editing-help.